# Why should we initialize data members on declaration (not necessarily on constructor)?

Tags: c++11

Does anyone could explain me the reason of this coding recommendation ?

> Since C++11, please initialize data members on declaration (not
> necessary on constructor) :
>
> ```
> class Limit
> {
> public:
>     Limit() = default;
>
> private:
>     int32_t quantity = 0;
>     double  price    = 0.0;
> };
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone thinks (correctly) that this way the variable is always initialised. Which is a good thing if it is initialised with a meaningful value and bad if the value is not meaningful. For example a person’s year of birth is a number from say 1890 to 2021. Initialising it to 0 isn’t useful and can only prevent the compiler from warning you.

So do this if you have a value that is *always* a useful initialisation value. I wouldn’t do it for anything that is likely to be overwritten in a constructor or shortly after.

Comment: But if you define your default constructor, it will be always initialised, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer from [CppCoreGuidelines C-48](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c48-prefer-in-class-initializers-to-member-initializers-in-constructors-for-constant-initializers) :

**C.48: Prefer in-class initializers to member initializers in constructors for constant initializers**

**Reason**

Makes it explicit that the same value is expected to be used in all constructors. Avoids repetition. Avoids maintenance problems. It leads to the shortest and most efficient code.

**Example, bad**

```
class X {   // BAD
    int i;
    string s;
    int j;
public:
    X() :i{666}, s{"qqq"} { }   // j is uninitialized
    X(int ii) :i{ii} {}         // s is "" and j is uninitialized
    // ...
};
```

How would a maintainer know whether `j` was deliberately uninitialized (probably a bad idea anyway) and whether it was intentional to give `s` the default value `""` in one case and `qqq` in another (almost certainly a bug)? The problem with `j` (forgetting to initialize a member) often happens when a new member is added to an existing class.

**Example**

```
class X2 {
    int i {666};
    string s {"qqq"};
    int j {0};
public:
    X2() = default;        // all members are initialized to their defaults
    X2(int ii) :i{ii} {}   // s and j initialized to their defaults
    // ...
};
```

**Alternative:** We can get part of the benefits from default arguments to constructors, and that is not uncommon in older code. However, that is less explicit, causes more arguments to be passed, and is repetitive when there is more than one constructor:

```
class X3 {   // BAD: inexplicit, argument passing overhead
    int i;
    string s;
    int j;
public:
    X3(int ii = 666, const string& ss = "qqq", int jj = 0)
        :i{ii}, s{ss}, j{jj} { }   // all members are initialized to their defaults
    // ...
};
```

**Enforcement**

(Simple) Every constructor should initialize every member variable (either explicitly, via a delegating ctor call or via default construction).

(Simple) Default arguments to constructors suggest an in-class initializer might be more appropriate.

There is also [the guideline C-45](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c45-dont-define-a-default-constructor-that-only-initializes-data-members-use-in-class-member-initializers-instead)  that explains it.